# How are the default MVC Controllers added to the route table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We says that the MVC request is processed by the controller/action which are mapped in the Routetable.

In routeconfig file, there is only one (default) route is mapped. But how all the controller/action excecuted correctly. How the other routes are added in the routetable ?

Comment: You might want to tell us what technology/framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The default route works by convention, which looks for classes in the `Controllers` folder that end with the word controller (i.e. *Orders**Controller***).  In this case the route will automatically be added to your routing table.

You can find the full documentation for ASP.Net Routing here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I can understand. If that is the case, then why we add in MapRoute() as Default for some controller/action in routeconfig file.

Comment: You could use MapRoute to add additional constraints to the route or to craft custom URL schemes such as `http://example.com/MyController/123/Details`.

Comment: Without a default route, you'll likely receive a Runtime Error stating `Server Error in '/' Application` unless you have a file in your project that matches that same path.  See this section of the MSDN documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_7

Comment: Technically the view part has nothing to do with request routing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading here to fully understand how ASP.NET routing works. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs